# Operator precedence in Java with assignment

Tags: java, variable-assignment, operator-precedence

Can anyone help me understand the logic behind the following results?

Case 1.

```java
int x,a = 100;
x = a + (a=6);
System.out.println(x);  //prints 106
```

Case 2.

```java
int x,a =100;
x = (a=6) + a;
System.out.println(x);  //prints 12
```

why a=6 not evaluate first in 1st case

Comment: But in  10-10/5  10/5 evaluate first due to precedence. Here we have parenthesis. But why is it not evaluated frist?

Comment: This got closed while I was writing my answer (hate it when that happens).  But to summarise - The rule with all the Java binary operators is that the left side is evaluated completely first, then the right side is evaluated completely, and then the operator is executed.  In your first example, the left hand side is evaluated to give 100.  Then the right had side is evaluated to give 6.  Then the two sides are added together to give 106.  In the example from your comment, the left side of `-` is evaluated to give 10, and then the right side is evaluated to give 2, so the result is 8.

Comment: In other words, operator precedence is not the same concept as evaluation order.

Comment: *Operands* of operators are evaluated left to right. @PresidentJamesK.Polk

Comment: that is not operator precedence, but evaluation order of a binary operation - Java Language Specification [15.7.1. Evaluate Left-Hand Operand First](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7.1): "*The left-hand operand of a binary operator appears to be fully evaluated before any part of the right-hand operand is evaluated.*"